# Error con 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' en CORS

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, cors

Buenas estoy haciendo una aplicación con React, nodeJs, mongodb y express. Ultimamente se me esta produciendo este error:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3900/xxx/xxx' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

La conexión a la base de datos la hago de la siguiente forma:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:xxx/xxx',{ useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true})
        .then(()=>{
            console.log('La conexion a la BD se ha realizado con exito');

           
        });
const port=  3900 ;

app.listen(port, host, ()=> {
    console.log('servidor corriendo en http://localhost:'+port + " " + host);

});
```

En app.js tengo la siguiente declaración para los CORS:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
});
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: tienes instalado cors en tu proyecto ?

Comment: si, tengo instalado cors en su ultima version

Comment: configuralo directamente: `import cors from 'cors'
app.use(cors())
`

Comment: he usado tambien eso, y me sigue mostrando el mismo error